# Necessity of boundeness of domain in Strong Maximum Principle

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, linear-pde

The Strong Maximum Principle for $c \geq 0$ is as fallowing:

Assume $u \in C^{2}(U) \cap C(\overline{U})$ and
$$
c \geq 0 \text{ in } U.
$$
Supose also $U$ is connected.

i) If
$$
Lu \leq 0 \text{ in } U
$$
and $u$ attains a nonnegative maximum over $\overline{U}$ at an interior point, then $u$ is constant within $U$.

ii)  Similarly, if
$$
Lu \geq 0\text{ in } U
$$
and $u$ attains a nonpositive minimum over $\overline{U}$ at an interior point, then $u$ is constant within $U$.

I took the result above from Evans, 2010, page 350, Theorem 4.

Sometimes it's not clear for me whether the domain $U$ really needs to be bounded or not for this result. In this case, the domain should be necessarily bounded?

Answer (score 2):

For this the proof works without assuming boundedness.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need the assumption of boundedness for this particular proof. Still, it is indeed needed for the proof of part (i) using part (ii) as to prove part (i) on the closure of each connected component one needs the existence of maximum, if it's not there, part (i) of the theorem is not really true!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).